# Trying to reproduce results from StackGAN paper on Text-to-Photo synthesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to run the StackGAN code on aws ec2 but the demo does not work. I have downloaded the text-embeddings and preprocessed the data.

However I keep getting this error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Data/birds/example_captions.t7'
```

I have tried to manually install pytorch but the build fails on ec2
I have also went into the torch environment pytorch_p27 provided but the same error occurs

I have downloaded some pretrained models in the hopes that those will allow me to perform the StackGAN birds demo included in the repo.

But, I cannot get past this error.

Comment: Did you find out how to get this file?  I am experiencing the same issue!  It's referencing a file that was not there when I downloaded it the repo

Answer (score -1):

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Data/birds/example_captions.t7'

That's what you get when mistype or place your file, have you try to confirm that the example_captions.t7 file is in the directory that it's asking for?

Comment: Originally the file wasen’t there so I created one but it yielded the same results. In the stackGAN github code there is a demo .sh file that takes a txt file and turns it into a t7 file. I think this is a torchvision file. On ec2 torchvision and torch are installed however th command returns not found. Other sources have said to source from .bash_profile I put the torch install in there. But I don’t know how to do this on ec2.